# Product price as per date

Tags: magento-1.9

One of my client have requirement to change product price on frontend as per date selection. On product page, one date picker will be there and on date selection that product price should be changed.

Is there any module available in free/paid? Or any links or suggestions to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this extension is helpful for your requirement

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/date-price-range-option.html

here is frontend demo [link](http://hottons.com/demo/pf/electronics/cell-phones/htc-touch-diamond.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own input type for custom options to show a date picker instead of a regular text field or dropdown.

These answers over at StackOverflow should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500144/how-to-create-new-custom-options-type-in-magento